# JSON Not converting long numbers appropriately

Tags: json, numbers, converters

I have a simple JSON where number is not getting parsed properly.

```
[
  {
    "orderNumber": 1,
    "customerId": 228930314431312345,
    "shoppingCartId": 22893031443137109,
    "firstName": "jjj"
  }
]
```

I tried it @ http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/ and the result was

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<orderNumber>1</orderNumber>
<customerId>228930314431312350</customerId>
<shoppingCartId>22893031443137108</shoppingCartId>
<firstName>jjj</firstName>
```

As you can see....the XML is different from JSON. I'm new to JSON. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a Javascript precision problem.

According to Mozilla Developer Network:

> ECMA-262 only requires a precision of up to 21 significant digits. Other implementations may not support precisions higher than required by the standard.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision

I pasted your array into Google Chrome's Javascript console and got back this:
[image: Javascript precision bug]

So it looks like Javascript is rounding the values before they are being converted to XML. Since your conversion is being done via Javascript in the browser at http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/, it makes sense why the number was changed.

(Note: I tested on Google Chrome version 26.0.1410.43 m using Windows 7 Professional)

**Edit:**

Is there any reason why you cannot pass these values to Javascript as strings?

Try this:

```
[
  {
    "orderNumber": "1",
    "customerId": "228930314431312345",
    "shoppingCartId": "22893031443137109",
    "firstName": "jjj"
  }
]
```

I was able to do this and save the values successfully. However, you will not be able to run a math calculation on them in Javascript without losing some precision, unless you are doing something like multiplying by 0, of course.

[image: Javascript precision string workaround]

This also converted to XML correctly using your reference http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/.

Comment: I had tried on IE 9 and Chrome. Basically, I am trying to get a JSON response from my Spring MVC controller and am getting invalid values. I used the XML converter just to show request/response. Thanks! I tried gson and jackson.

Comment: @Jeet - See my **Edit**. I have found a workaround that may work for your purposes.

Comment: Well..I can pass them as strings, but wouldn't that be manual intervention? I was hoping for an out of the box solution.

Comment: @Jeet - The moment you create that large value as **Numeric** in Javascript, it will lose precision.

Comment: @Jeet - How are you generating your JSON?

Comment: I am making an Ajax call to Controller which is returing a model object with these IDs. I tried Jackson to convert it automatically and then tried gson to convert to json and return String. ResponseBody <Cart> (with Jackson) and ResponseBody String with gson.

Answer (score 6):

Javascript represents its numbers as double precision floats which limits the largest integer number that can be represented to +-9007199254740992. Here is the [ECMA](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type) documentation.

Comment: Fixed some time back