# How can I force Jackson to write numbers as strings when serializing my objects

Tags: java, javascript, json, jackson

I have an id that is pretty large on one of my java objects. When it jackson converts it to JSON it sends it down as a number (e.g. {"id":1000110040000000001}) but as soon as it becomes a javascript object the id gets changed to 1000110040000000000. I read about this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869275/json-not-converting-long-numbers-appropriately)

It works fine when the id is smaller. My first thought is to just force Jackson to convert all the numbers to strings but I am open to other options as well. If possible I would prefer not to add Jackson annotations to my java objects.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12046979/2129835

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Apparently in version 2.1.3 you can do something like this: @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class). It still would be nice if I could just set some overall setting in the object mapper, but this will do if that is not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jackson JSON custom serialization for certain fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046786/jackson-json-custom-serialization-for-certain-fields)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Jackson-databind (at least 2.1.3) provides special ToStringSerializer. That did it for me.

```
@Id @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
private Long id;
```

Answer (score 21):

`com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.4` provides 
JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS for `ObjectMapper` configuration.

```
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS, true);

Foo foo = new Foo(10);
System.out.println("Output: " + objectMapper.writeValueAsString(foo));
```

> Output: {"a":"1"}

```
class Foo {
    @XmlElement(name = "a")
    Integer a
}
```

To include the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks!  This approach lets me serialize auto-generated classes in the way I want without needing to alter the class definition

Comment: in application.properties, you can use `spring.jackson.generator.write-numbers-as-strings=true`

Comment: The syntax has changed. It's deprecated to use `JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS` or to use `mapper.configure()`. I'm trying to figure out the latest syntax.