# How to prevent Jackson from automatically rounding up large numbers

Tags: java, spring, jackson

We are using Spring MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter to convert our data to json resources.

We have noticed that if the record id is a large number such as eg:1234567891234567891 the converted resource id (record id is the resource id) is automatically rounded up to 1234567891234568000.

It seems the Jackson can't handle the larger number or is it some limitation in javascript/json number representations?

Following is our current MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter configurations

```
Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();

    DateFormat defaultResourceDateOutputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            DEFAULT_INTERNAL_DATE_FORMAT);
    builder.dateFormat(defaultResourceDateOutputFormat);
    builder.timeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    builder.serializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
    builder.featuresToDisable(
            DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    builder.defaultViewInclusion(Boolean.TRUE);
```

I have referred [Large numbers erroneously rounded in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379934/large-numbers-erroneously-rounded-in-javascript)
 but not sure it's caused by the same reason.

Appreciate any feedback. Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052314/how-can-i-force-jackson-to-write-numbers-as-strings-when-serializing-my-objects?

Comment: Thanks chrylis but that means we need to convert the number to a String right? I don't think we can do it in our situation.

Comment: Why not? An ID is supposed to be essentially opaque, not something with intrinsic semantic value (e.g., you're not going to be performing math operations on it).

Comment: Also to do that we need add @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class) to each and every entity right? Im looking for an easy way like some configuration in Jackson to do that instead of touching all the entities. By the way thanks again

Comment: Pretty much. There just isn't any other way; in JSON, you just have double-valued "numbers".

Comment: @chrylis as you said there is no any other way to go and therefore we decided to use @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class) and seems it does the job. I just wanted to know why does the default jackson serializer failed to prevent this and  also as I understand ToStringSerializer.class is using toString() before write as json. How does it prevent the rounding up?