# Jackson 2.14: Serialize all fields cast to Strings

Tags: java, jackson

In the latest Jackson 2.14 you can't use `WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS` which is deprecated:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS, true); // DEPRECATED!
```

Also you can't use `@JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)`:

[image]

These were the suggestions offered in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052314/how-can-i-force-jackson-to-write-numbers-as-strings-when-serializing-my-objects). So how do we now cast fields to Strings in the latest Jackson? Some examples would be appreciated, because I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the new convention. It's now called `JsonWriteFeature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRING)` and also `.configure()` needs to be put after `JsonMapper.builder()`.

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
                                    .configure(JsonWriteFeature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS, true) 
                                    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting a method as a setter for your value. This method then converts your integer to a string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    String json = "{\"number\": 1}";
    Model model = mapper.readValue(json, Model.class);
    System.out.println(model.getNumber());
}


public class Model {
  private String number;

  public void setNumber(@JsonProperty("number") Integer number) {
    this.number = Integer.toString(number);
  }

  public String getNumber() {
    return number;
  }
}
```