# Integer overflow - golang

Tags: go

I am experiencing some integer overflow error.
I have a micro service application built using golang and go-micro as micro service framework.
And I am using NATS as message broker.

my micro service payloads are in the format

```
 map[string]interface{}
```

The problem occurs when I publish a payload which contains a uint64 such as

```
 var id uint64 = 512281913614499841

 message := map[string]inteface{}
 message["id"] = id
```

(this is a unique ID generated by cockroachdb), when a subscriber receives this message as byte and unmarshals this to a uint64, i realize that a overflow occurs and the value becomes

```
512281913614499840 //this should be 512281913614499841
```

notice the 0 at the end instead of 1

I have created 2 functions (overFlowError and noOverflow) - see below.

the function overFlowError simulates code that causes overflow

and noOverflow prints the correct result because i use payload in this format map[string][struct] instead of map[string]interface

```
type UserType struct {
    Email string `json:"email"`
    ID    int64  `json:"id"`
}
func overFlowError() {

        var id int64 = 512281913614499841

        user := UserType{
            Email: "example",
            ID:    id,
        }

        message := map[string]interface{}{
            "data": user,
        }

        //mashal to byte to simulate service payload
        servicePayload, err := json.Marshal(message)

        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }

        var receivedMessage map[string]interface{}

        json.Unmarshal(servicePayload, &receivedMessage)

        var myUser UserType

        mapstructure.Decode(receivedMessage["data"], &myUser)

        log.Println("---receivedMessage:", myUser.ID) //prints 512281913614499840 - incorrect
    }
```

No over flow

```
type UserType struct {
    Email string `json:"email"`
    ID    int64  `json:"id"`
}
func noOverflow() {

        var id int64 = 512281913614499841

        message := map[string]UserType{}

        message["data"] = UserType{
            Email: "example",
            ID:    id,
        }

        byteMessage, err := json.Marshal(message)

        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }

        var msgMap map[string]UserType

        json.Unmarshal(byteMessage, &msgMap)

        log.Println("---myUser:", msgMap["data"].ID) // prints 512281913614499841 - correct
    }
```

to over avoid a lot of code rewrite, I am left with the first option which i have simulated in the overFlowError function and also explained above

is there a fix to this problem?

Comment: can you please add the code from your repo to this question?

Comment: This is because the value of `id` overflowing `float64`'s range of precision. You can marshal it as a string and parse it when receiving, or use `json.Decoder` with `json.Decoder.UseNumber` instead of `json.Unmarshal` and then parse the number.

Comment: Thanks leaf, i tried the first solution earlier, however it  did not feel like the best solution because a string is not the intended type. I am searching for a more natural and elegant solution. For the second solution, I am thinking of how that would work for a uint64 field in a struct such as this : type User struct{ID uint64} as this also overflows when deserializing. ill have a look at the json.decoder package

Comment: @ykel what numeric properties are you looking from the `ID` field so that you don't want it to become a string? Do you add, subtract, divide or multiply it?

Comment: @zerkms,  if nothing else better works,  i'll go with the first solution from leaf.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an integer overflow.  As [leaf bebop noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59345509/integer-overflow-golang#comment104887561_59345509), the problem is actually that JSON numbers tend to get represented as floating-point, and `float32` has too few bits to hold the correct value.  Even `float64`, which Go uses by default, is not quite adequate.

See *all* the answers to [JSON integers: limit on size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13502398/1256452) (not just the accepted one), and [Tom Christie's comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502398/json-integers-limit-on-size#comment80159722_13502497).  Or, see the older question [JSON Not converting long numbers appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15869275/1256452) with its accepted answer.

Depending on what kind of interoperability you need, you can continue to decode these as numbers but use a trickier decoder and/or custom unmarshaler, or just resort to having it encoded *in* JSON as a string.  In practice, when using JSON across Go + Python + TypeScript + various C++ libraries, we<sup>1</sup> have resorted to string encoding.  We found this to be far more reliable in the end.  (We have not had to do this for 32-bit integers, just for the 64-bit ones.)

To use a non-default decoder, see in particular [`json.NewDecoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#NewDecoder) and its [`UseNumber`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.UseNumber) option.

---

<sup>1</sup>"We" here is not the royal "we", but rather $job, where I have touched all of these except for TypeScript.